# Why do we say that in dynamic web-pages we can't make any changes?

Tags: dynamic, server

When we enter our credentials, the mail box opens which is sent from the server. But we are able to manipulate it like deleting messages, or moving messages from one folder to another.

And next time we re-login it is in the same status, although the page again came from the server.

It means that the changes we made were saved on the server.

Then why do we say that we can't make changes to dynamic web-pages sent by the server to the client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right.

When you move E-Mails in another folder or do something else on the website, your changes will take effect on the server not on your client. So you don't really change the dynamic web-page, you change content properties on the server. For example a Message could have an ID and then theres a Table which will Map Messages by Id to Folders. When you move a Message to another Folder, Database Entries on the server will be updated.

Comment: Yes you got the question right.  My point is that when we are able to make changes, is it not changing the dynamic web-page ?

Comment: Since we are getting the manipulated web page after that whenever we re-login

Comment: Hmm no. The WebPage on Server Side is always the same. But the Dynamic WebPage contains Variables etc. which will be filled by the result you will get from the Server (Dynamic Content) which will make the Website look different for every Person that accesses the WebSite.

Comment: Now I understood. We can update database entries at the server but not the presentation tier page. The web page will always be the same but through it we can interact with server database. After that whenever the page will load it will show the latest details

Comment: retrieved from the database